# BroadcastReceiver is not firing properly after boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Problem in my app is that OnBootResetAlarmReceiver is called only if have opened my app after boot . It won't be called until I open my app after boot.
I have added both BOOT_COMPLETED permission and intent filter in manifest

I want my OnBootResetAlarmReceiver to be called automatically after boot without opening the app.

As you can see i have added Log and Toast but I am not able to see any of them after boot until i open my app. Am I missing something?

OnBootResetAlarmReceiver.java

```
public class OnBootResetAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = TodoOpenHelper.getOpenHelperInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    int count = 0;
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TodoOpenHelper.TODO_TABLE, null, TodoOpenHelper.TODO_ALARM_STATUS+ " = 1", null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        count++;

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoOpenHelper.TODO_TASK));
        long timeInEpoch = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoOpenHelper.TODO_TIME));
        int pendingIntentId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoOpenHelper.TODO_PENDING_INTENT_ID));


        Intent showNotificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowNotificationReceiver.class);
        showNotificationIntent.putExtra(IntentConstants.TODO_TITLE, title);
        showNotificationIntent.putExtra(IntentConstants.TODO_PENDING_ID, pendingIntentId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, pendingIntentId, showNotificationIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInEpoch, pendingIntent);


    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "On boot receiver, count ="+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("MyAppBootReceiver", "count = "+count);
    cursor.close();

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sahni.rahul.todo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/TodoTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/TodoTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.AddTodoActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcastReceivers.ShowNotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcastReceivers.OnBootResetAlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcastReceivers.NotificationActionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Comment: How long did you wait to open the app after restarting the device? In my experience the `onBootReciever` does not fire instantly and it is possible to open the app before the receiver runs

Comment: @MacLeanSochor i waited till the time for which i have set alarm has elapsed